# Laravel Excel - Export Excel and change the cell format to a summable time

Tags: php, excel, laravel, phpspreadsheet, laravel-excel

I'm using Laravel Excel having problems changing the cell format to a time that can be summed.

This is my code in app/Exports/DataExcel.php

```
public function registerEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            AfterSheet::class => function (AfterSheet $event) {
                $event->sheet->getDelegate()
                    ->getStyle('H4:H1000')
                    ->getNumberFormat(NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_TIME3);

            },
        ];
    }
```

This is my column table view

[image]

This is the export excel result:

[image]

What if when I export the column already has a time format and I can SUM it up without having to change the format for each column.

Comment: check if `$event->sheet->setCellValue('H1001', '=SUM(H4:H1000)');` whorks

Comment: No, @MahdiRashidi i want cell in H4:H1000 format time not string (ex: '03:00).

Comment: It doesn't work or you are just saying you dont want string format?

Comment: `$event->sheet->setCellValue('H1001', '=SUM(H4:H1000)');`
`$event->sheet->getStyle('H1001')->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode(NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_TIME3);`

Comment: Have you had any breakthroughs?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/tY3ntA7.png
No. 1 = Text still string format because text "align left".
No. 2 = Works, Input new Text format duration time, "align right".
I want my exported text to change to duration time format, it will automatically be on the align right. So that I can sum in any column. @MahdiRashidi

Comment: Did u try setFormatCode which I commented?

Comment: Yes, i try @MahdiRashidi but still not working.